# Using XDebug with Eclipse PDT & XAMPP

Tags: eclipse, xampp, xdebug

I cannot debug a PHP script as a script.  It always terminates immediately after starting.  I set up an Xdebug log in my php.ini, but it's completely unhelpful.  Xdebug *does* show up on my phpinfo(), so I know it's loaded in Apache.

I can also debug code as a webpage (which provides no info on variables and will not stop on breakpoints though), so I know Eclipse has the proper server settings.  Both debug options use the same PHP exe (the one installed with XAMPP, php 5.3.1 compiled with vc6 compiler).  I made sure that the compilation of Xdebug matched these settings.

On a perhaps related note:  I noticed that I could only load Xdebug with the zend_extension command, instead of zend_extension_ts even though my version of PHP is indeed thread safe?  I have to admit I'm a little confused by that.

I also made very sure that wherever I could select "XDebug" in Eclipse, I did.  I've followed two tutorials to no avail here.  Anyone have any ideas?  I've tried the version of Xdebug bundled with my XAMPP (2.0.6-dev) and I also downloaded a new .dll, version 2.1.

Thanks!

Answer (score 6):

[Excellent instructions for Setup XDebug on XAMPP and Eclipse](http://munim.tumblr.com/post/917355998/how-to-setup-xdebug-on-xampp-and-eclipse)
@user629300 Instructions are good for eclipse versions prior to 3.5 see the links to get instructions for version based instructions. Also [Getting XDebug to work with apache xampp to debug php](http://unitstep.net/blog/2009/01/26/getting-xdebug-to-work-with-apachexampp-to-debug-php/), has pictures with good explanations. They are a little stale though.

---

A summary of the details from the first link, assuming PHP > 5.3 (which hopefully everyone is running now!):

- Make sure that your php.ini file contains the following:

  ```
  [XDebug]
  zend_extension={xampp-folder}\php\ext\php_xdebug.dll
  xdebug.remote_enable=1
  xdebug.remote_host="localhost"
  xdebug.remote_port=9000
  xdebug.remote_handler="dbgp"
  ```
- Remove any config entries under the `[Zend]` heading, particularly those starting with `zend_extension`
- Configure Eclipse:

  - in Window -> Preferences -> PHP -> Servers, configure the PHP server to use XDebug, add the base URL and local web root
  - in -> Installed debuggers, configure XDebug to accept remote sessions
  - (optional?) configure the PHP executable to point to php.exe in your XAMPP installation

You should now be able to hit breakpoints in Eclipse by adding `XDEBUG_SESSION_START` to the query string of your URL, e.g. `http://localhost/?XDEBUG_SESSION_START`.

Comment: Pro tip for fools like me who blindly dumped the config lines from the example in the first link and couldn't get it working: the quotes used are _smart_ i.e. `“` and `”` - they should be changed to regular double quotes `"`.

Comment: Don't forget to stop, then restart, Apache, to cause the new PHP.INI to be read

Comment: You can use this Chrome plugin to define de XDEBUG_SESSION_START when you want to debug. This with help you with the POST call. https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/xdebug-helper/eadndfjplgieldjbigjakmdgkmoaaaoc?hl=fr

Answer (score -1):

first download the dll for xDebug
then edit your php.ini file
zend_extension_ts = “C:\xampp\php\zendOptimizer\lib\ZendExtensionManager.dll”
make sure the line is uncommented
restart apache
make sure you are editing the right php.ini file